# Python 2.7 check if there is a file with a specific file name

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, filenames

I want to check if there is a file in a folder that its name contains a specific string, like:

folder:

-- hi.txt

-- bye.txt

-- bedanagain.txt

-- dan1.txt

-- dan2.txt

-- gray.txt

return true if in the folder there is a file with "dan" in its name.

Plus, If possible, I need to use the most well known imports (the customer is nervous about using unknown open source packages) and the smallest number of imports.

I tried using os.path.exists but I found that it works only if you have the full filename, and it wasn't able to search for a file name that contains some string.

I tried:

```
import os
print os.path.exists('./dan') // false
print os.path.exists('./dan*') // false
print os.path.exists('./*dan') // false
```

That is also why this is not a duplicate - I checked the mentioned feed, it deals with "if a file exists" and not "if a file with some string in its name exists"

Thanks!

Comment: Please follow the posting guidelines, i.e., post your attempts and what's wrong with them.

Comment: Also, if by "the most well known imports" you mean the python standard library, you're in trouble: it's all open source.

Comment: You can use the `os` or `glob` module.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check whether a file exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/how-to-check-whether-a-file-exists)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `OS` module.

**Ex:**

```
import os
for file in os.listdir(Path):
    if "dan" in file:
        print(file)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `os.listdir("dir path")` to get all files in directory in list and check for file name in that list:

```
import os
def check_file():
    x = os.listdir("path to dir")
    for i in x:
        if ["hi","bye","bedanagain","dan1","dan2","gray"] in i:
            return True
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mac, try having a look at the 'os' module (it should be built into your computer) you can import it with:

```
import os
```

You can run shell commands from within python using

```
os.system("your command")
```

For example

```
os.system("echo "This is terminal"")
```

I'm sure there is a terminal command that will let you check folders for specific files.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question